# using docker-compose.debug.yml from Visual studio for debugging purposes

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm having `docker-compose.yml` which content I'm not supposed to change. Is it possible to use `docker-compose.debug.yml` which I would use to override `docker-compose.yml` content but only inside Visual Studio Debug and Docker profile (defined in `appsettings.json`)?

`docker-compose.debug.yml` will have an image built from local dev image file, different ports, ...

The goal is to have dockerized local instance for debugging purposes and preserve original `docker-compose.yml` which content I'm not allowed to change.

Is this the right approach?

Do I in this case need to define specifically docker-compose.debug.yml from `launchSettings.json` Docker profile using `commandArguments` or it will be automatically called (and skip docker-compose.yml) in Visual Studio Debug & Docker profile selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio with default project configuration is building your Docker images from 3 different docker-compose files: `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.override.yml`, and `docker-compose.vs.debug.yml`. The second and the third allows you to override values from original `docker-compose.yml`. `Docker-compose.override.yml` should be automatically created by VS with the whole project and I would recommend to go with this one.

However, you can also add manually `docker-compose.vs.debug.yml` in the same directory where main `docker-compose.yml` is. It would be grabbed automatically during debugging session and override values from both `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files. Additional feature for this file is ability to set some specific debugging labels used by Visual Studio. See [file-labels documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019#docker-compose-file-labels).

For overriding docker-compose values, you can just repeat it in the second compose file (like docker-compose.vs.debug.yml) But for more specific usage, please follow [docker-compose adding and overriding instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration).

## Advanced Scenarios

For more sophisticated scenarios you can edit VisualStudio `.dcproj` (responsible for building and debugging your images) and include your additional docker-compose files (which will override the original setup). It will work during debug session but not harm `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml`. For this purpose you can use property `AdditionalComposeFilePaths`, see [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019).

So the project file might look like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Windows</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>154022c1-8014-4e9d-bd78-6ff46670ffa4</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>{Scheme}://{ServiceIPAddress}{ServicePort}</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>webapplication1</DockerServiceName>
    <DockerComposeBaseFilePath>DockerComposeFiles\mydockercompose</DockerComposeBaseFilePath>
    <AdditionalComposeFilePaths>AdditionalComposeFiles\myadditionalcompose.yml</AdditionalComposeFilePaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="DockerComposeFiles\mydockercompose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>DockerComposeFiles\mydockercompose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="DockerComposeFiles\mydockercompose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If you want completely replace the original `docker-compose.yml` you can always change only `DockerComposeBaseFilePath` property to your own. But it could be inconvenient to maintain the complete copy of original setup.